# MySQL: check if data exist inside query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

I never used "if-else" or "case" inside a sql-query, but I guess I need to this time.
I have a table whose data represents something like a competition between two users:

```
//properties of "competition-table
    int competitionId
    int userId_Contrahent1
    int userId_Contrahent2
    otherdata....
```

Users can vote for one or the other contrahent within that competition; a vote is represented like so:

```
//properties of vote-table
    int voteId
    int competitionId
    int userId_Voter
    int userId_Winner // the user for which this vote counts
    otherdata....
```

Obviously every given user in my Webapplication can only vote once for any given competition. So when I query for the competition I also want to have the information if the currentUser (which owns the current session) already voted for this competition. So in addition to all the other properties of competition I like to have an additional one, that has a key like "voted" and a value like "yes" or "no".
So my select statement should look something like this I guess:

```
SELECT competition.*,
If EXISTS ( 
  SELECT * FROM vote WHERE userId_Voter = $currentUserId 
  AND competitionId = competition.competitionId)
  ...do something
FROM competition;
```

How do I do that exactly in MySQL?

Comment: to create new column you do ALTER TABLE tablename ADD cloumnname tinyint();

Comment: @Breezer: I cant add for every existing user in my webapp another column to the competition-table!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   SELECT c.*,
          IF(v.competitionId IS NOT NULL, 'voted', 'not voted') AS `verdict`
     FROM competition c
LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.competitionId = c.competitionId
                AND v.userId_Voter = $currentUserId
```

Comment: if the value is "voted" or "not voted" what is the key of the property?